# Tangent Surface to a 4D Surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I have been typing up notes for Multivariable Calculus. While doing so I have been pondering the terms I ought to use for higher dimensional surfaces and the associated tangent surfaces. With a curve  in $\mathbb R^2$ the tangent "surface" is a line. With a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ the tangent surface is a plane. However, this is where I am stuck... What is the equivalent tangen surface to a given surface in $\mathbb R^4$? Intuition tells me that it would be a rectangular prism with infinite length on each edge and thus infinite volume, but I am not even sure of this, not to mention what I ought to call such a surface in my notes. Thus far I have simply called the tangent surface in $\mathbb R^n$ an $n$-plane, but this doesn't seem very formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference is to use specific and familiar terms as far as possible, and to make sure we don't damage any intuitive notions already understood from two and three dimensions. So I would call the tangent space of a 2D or 3D curve the "tangent line", and I'd call the tangent space of a 3D surface a "tangent plane". For a 4D object, "tangent space" seems appropriate. A "space" is "fatter" than a plane, so the term is somewhat accurate. Calling it a "tangent surface" doesn't seem right, because it's not a surface in the usual sense of the word.

Comment: This seems quite reasonable... thank you for the response!! Is there a commonly accepted term for this in $n$-space? Would you recommend I simply refer to it as the "tangent space" for all dimensions above 3?

Comment: in general, an equation of the form $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n=D$ where $n>3$, is called a hyperplane, so I suppose it would make sense to call it a "tangent hyperplane"?

Comment: As far as I know, the standard terms are "tangent space" or "tangent hyperplane". I like "space" because it's a shorter word and it implies some fatness.